# How to make an HTML list stay in position when dynamically adding new <LI>s to a different list

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, button

I have 2 lists and Im using JavaScript to add a new list item to one list. I want to add in a description on that item that the user adds if they want to. The problem is that when they add the task to list one, it moves down my list 2, which i want to be positioned to be in-line with the first list.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Task:</label>
    <input id="task" name="task" type='text'/>

    <label>Task Description:</label>
    <input id='desc' name='desc' type='text'/>
    <br><br>

    <button id='buttontask'>Add Task</button>
    <button id='buttondesc'>Add Task Description</button>
    <br><br>

    <hr>

    <p class='tasktitle'><strong>Tasks</strong></p>
    <ol id='list1'>
    </ol>

    <div class='list2'>
      <ol id='list2'>
      </ol>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
  <script src='appTask1.js'></script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.list2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  display: ru;
  top: -48px;
}

.tasktitle {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function start() {
  var buttontask = document.getElementById("buttontask");
  var task = document.getElementById("task");
  var list1 = document.getElementById("list1");

  buttontask.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var newE = document.createElement('LI');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(task.value);

    newE.appendChild(textnode);

    newE.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
    newE.classList.add(task.value);
    list1.appendChild(newE);
  });
};

start();


function start1() {
  var buttondesc = document.getElementById("buttondesc");
  var list2 = document.getElementById("list2");
  var desc = document.getElementById("desc");

  buttondesc.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var newE = document.createElement('LI');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(desc.value);

    newE.appendChild(textnode);

    newE.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });

    newE.classList.add(desc.value);
    list2.appendChild(newE);
  });
};

start1();
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @Sarhang There's no indication of it.

Comment: Im not using bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a wrapper class around the lists

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ol id='list1'></ol>
  <ol id='list2'></ol>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.wrapper{ 
  display:flex;
 }

.wrapper>*{ 
  flex:1;
 }
```

```js
function start() {
  var buttontask = document.getElementById("buttontask");
  var task = document.getElementById("task");
  var list1 = document.getElementById("list1");

  buttontask.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var newE = document.createElement('LI');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(task.value);

    newE.appendChild(textnode);

    newE.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
    newE.classList.add(task.value);
    list1.appendChild(newE);
  });
};

start();


function start1() {
  var buttondesc = document.getElementById("buttondesc");
  var list2 = document.getElementById("list2");
  var desc = document.getElementById("desc");

  buttondesc.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var newE = document.createElement('LI');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(desc.value);

    newE.appendChild(textnode);

    newE.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });

    newE.classList.add(desc.value);
    list2.appendChild(newE);
  });
};

start1();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.tasktitle {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Task:</label>
    <input id="task" name="task" type='text' />

    <label>Task Description:</label>
    <input id='desc' name='desc' type='text' />
    <br><br>

    <button id='buttontask'>Add Task</button>
    <button id='buttondesc'>Add Task Description</button>
    <br><br>

    <hr>

    <p class='tasktitle'><strong>Tasks</strong></p>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ol id='list1'></ol>
      <ol id='list2'></ol>
    </div>


  </fieldset>
  <script src='appTask1.js'></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this code I came up with.

```js
    function start() {
      var buttontask = document.getElementById("buttontask");
      var task = document.getElementById("task");
      var list1 = document.getElementById("list1");

      buttontask.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var newE = document.createElement('LI');
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(task.value);

        newE.appendChild(textnode);

        newE.addEventListener('click', function() {
          this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        });
        newE.classList.add(task.value);
        list1.appendChild(newE);
      });
    };

    start();


    function start1() {
      var buttondesc = document.getElementById("buttondesc");
      var list2 = document.getElementById("list2");
      var desc = document.getElementById("desc");

      buttondesc.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var newE = document.createElement('LI');
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(desc.value);

        newE.appendChild(textnode);

        newE.addEventListener('click', function() {
          this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        });

        newE.classList.add(desc.value);
        list2.appendChild(newE);
      });
    };

    start1();
```

```css
.list2 {
      position: relative;
      left: 200px;
      display: ru;
      top: -48px;
      float: right
    }

    .tasktitle {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Task:</label>
    <input id="task" name="task" type='text'/>

    <label>Task Description:</label>
    <input id='desc' name='desc' type='text'/>
    <br><br>

    <button id='buttontask'>Add Task</button>
    <button id='buttondesc'>Add Task Description</button>
    <br><br>

    <hr>

    <p class='tasktitle'><strong>Tasks</strong></p>
    <ol id='list1'>
    <div class='list2'>
  <ol id='list2'  style="float:right">
  </ol>
</div>
    </ol>


  </fieldset>
  <script src='appTask1.js'></script>
</body>
```